# Attach event to hyperlink click inside update panel?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I am adding a click event (display alert on click) to a html hyperlink inside an UpdatePanel on document(ready). However, the event never gets fired when I click the hyperlink. Is it because of ASync postback? What is the correct way to do this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#addExcl').click(function(){
                alert('asassasaas');return false;
            });    
    });
```

Comment: *sigh* ... show some code, we can't guess what you are doing.

Comment: What you've described should work. We're going to need to code.

Comment: I have added the code bit, it works fine when I place the hyperlink outside my update panel but not when its inside the update panel. P.S: Can you set the -1 on my question back to 0 ? I have added the code now ._.

Comment: we would need some HTML code where this does not work as well, this is much too general to give you an answer... don't worry, this comunity will not steal your code, you can reveal a bit more :)

Comment: the html would just mean an update panel syntax.And, I never thought anyone of stealing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the even in every ajax update because the dom struct is change and the events are lost on the part of the update.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
         $('#addExcl').click(function(){
             alert('asassasaas');
             return false;
         }); 
}
```

Comment: Hi aristos, thanks for the reply. What if I used pageLoad instead ?

Comment: @popo this is the events that MS fires with every ajax update on the panel. I think that is better to attach it on the EndRequest to be sure that the control found.

Comment: Thanks Aristos, in my case its just a toggle hyperlink so no postback. But thanks for the explanation, thumbs up =)

Comment: @popo if you did not make postback, and you do not see the toggle on pageload, then maybe you have other javascript error. One javascript error can stop the rest javascript code. Check it out on the javascript error console. !